# Constructor cannot be resolved

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create an array adapter to populate my list view.

Below is the code I have however the Array Adapter gets the error "Cannot resolve constructor".

Can anybody please help me with why this might be happening?
Thanks.

```
private void populateListView(){
    //Create list of items'

    String[] myItems = {"Blue", "red", "green", "purple"};
    //Build adapter

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.deal_items, myItems);
    //Configure the list view

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `import` statement for `ArrayAdapter`? Is this method implemented in an `Activity`?

Comment: I have these import statements,

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: I guess **this** refers to Fragment, you need to pass a **Context**... so try with *getActivity()* instead of *this*

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor needs to be a `Context`. You appear to have implemented this method in a `Fragment`, which is not a `Context`. If so, then replace `this` in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor with `getActivity()`.